# Reason: Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

When am trying to authenticate the user through LDAP from database am getting the following error.

```
Reason: Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor.
```

Can anyone please tell me what am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">  

<http auto-config="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
<intercept-url pattern="/administrator.htm" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<!-- <form-login login-page="/dashboard.htm" default-target-url="/dashboard.htm" authentication-failure-url="/ExceptionPage.jsp" /> -->
<form-login/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<!--   <user-service>
<user name="20022263" password="da" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
<user name="20039004" password="da" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</user-service> -->
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
users-by-username-query="SELECT a.GLOBALID AS username, a.PASSWORD AS password, a.Enabled AS enabled FROM EU_MAS_TBUSER a WHERE a.GLOBALID=?" 
 authorities-by-username-query="select eu.USERNAME AS username, r.ACCESSROLEID AS authority from EU_MAS_TBUSER eu, EU_MAS_TBUSERS_ROLE r where eu.GLOBALID = r.GLOBALID and eu.GLOBALID=?" 
 role-prefix="ROLE_"/>   
</authentication-provider>

 </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The actual line that produces the exception is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/38492a5794e27e543da8801ca55ae4d7d314fbba/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L105). The relevant code where the user object is created is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/38492a5794e27e543da8801ca55ae4d7d314fbba/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java#L235).

So my best guess is that you have a null password field for the user in the database.

Note that if you are posting an error like this it's a lot easier to answer if you give the stacktrace and the relevant debug output from the server log.

Comment: This error occured in Login page itself, i haven't got any stacktrace :(

Comment: Hey Taylor, ur guess is correct.. its working  now.. thnx for ur valuable suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Status 401 : Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor

The server is expecting a query param but you are sending the wrong value in it.

So simpler answer is:

We need to send a valid query param what the server is expecting.